# How to select all inputs having same name and index them by their name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to handle a form generated by a third part. This form provides some checkbox "multi-select" attributes. But input name's are identical, and PHP $_POST can't handle identical keys (only the last data is handled).

Here is an example of the form :

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1" value="4" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr2" value="xx" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3" value="a" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3" value="b" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3" value="c" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3" value="d" />
    <input type="text" name="attr4" value="" />
</form>
```

I'd like to parse all checkbox inputs, get only group of same name inputs, and append "[]" to their name...

What I want to get after jQuery processing :

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="4" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr2" value="xx" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="a" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="b" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="c" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="d" />
    <input type="text" name="attr4" value="" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to identify group of inputs with same name ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with JavaScript and not modifying the markup directly?  I guess you don't mind alienating users with JS disabled, correct?

Comment: This HTML form is provided by a third part (XML transformed by XSL) and I don't want to modify the provided XSL (it is versioned and i get it from a webservice). And you're right, I don't deal with JS disabled users (it's not a public web site but an online service application).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will append `[]` to the name of each checkbox item if there exists another item with the same name.

```
var name_map = {};
$("input[type=checkbox]")  // for all checkboxes
    .each(function() {  // first pass, create name mapping
        var name = this.name;
        name_map[name] = (name_map[name]) ? name + "[]" : name;
    })
    .each(function() {  // replace name based on mapping
        this.name = name_map[this.name];
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gnfsG/

Comment: Not bad! +1 for a simple solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var group = $('input[name="attr1"]');

if (group.length > 1){
   group.each(function () {
        $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name")+"[]");
   });
}
```

Comment: I want to match only inputs having siblings with the same name, not all inputs. I don't know if it's actually possible...

Comment: Can you explain this in detail? Like only checkbox? In my answer I am changing name of only check box control using `:checkbox` selector.

Comment: I wanted to change name, ONLY if input has a sibling with the same name. That's why your solution is not perfect ;)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `$('input[name^="attr"]')` in your case. As your items has `attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3` etc. The above selector will match all.

You can check this in action @ http://jsfiddle.net/cT78Y/2/

```
$('input[name^="attr"]:checkbox').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name")+"[]");
});
```

This will give you.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr1[]" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr2[]" value="xx">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="a">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="b">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="c">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr3[]" value="d">
  <input type="text" name="attr4" value="">
</form>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very long solution

```
var array =[];
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                    array.push($(this).attr('name'));
                });

                var sorted_arr = array.sort(); // You can define the comparing function here.
                // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
                var results = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
                        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
                    }
                }
                var names = [];
                names = jQuery.unique(results);
                $.each(names ,function(key,value){
                    $('input[name ="'+value+'"]').attr("name",value+"[]");
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=attr\\[\\]]");
```

get all input where name = `attr[]`