# How to get the dynamic id by its name

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a table with so many rows which is also having a button in each row , so I put its Id dynamically like `id=@gunDetails.SerialNo`(for each row its different) and its name I gave as `name="popoverselect"` So now I want to get this dynamic Id . How can i get it I need the Id in my popup which will open when I click on that button.
I have tried `

```
var getVal = $('[name="popoverselect"]').attr(id);
```

but its not working, any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

```
 <td class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" @*data-toggle="tooltip"*@ title="Edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
      </div>
  </td>
```

This is my button which will show the popover so when I am trying

```
var getVal = $('[name="popoverselect"]').attr("id");
```

I am only getting the id of my first row

`

Comment: `$("[name='popoverselect']").attr("id");`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192731/how-to-select-all-inputs-having-same-name-and-index-them-by-their-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="1593" onclick="alert($(this).attr('id'))">Button 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="1678" onclick="alert($(this).attr('id'))">Button 2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select element by name like this

```
$("[name='popoverselect']");//select all elements with name equal to 'popoverselect'
$("[name*='popoverselect']");//select all elements with name contains 'popoverselect'
$("[name^='popoverselect']");//select all elements with name start with 'popoverselect'
```

And to get id use `$("[name='popoverselect']").attr("id");`

so for your example `.attr(id)` JQuery will look to `id` as variable witch not defined

```
var id = "id";
$("[name='popoverselect']").attr(id);//this will work
```